# print customized result in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am working on a simple prolog program. Here is my problem.

Say I already have a fact `fruit(apple).`

I want the program take a input like this `?- input([what,is,apple]).`

and output `apple is a fruit`

and for input like `?-input([is,apple,a,fruit])`

instead of default print `true` or `false`, I want the program print some better phrase like `yes` and `no`

Can someone help me with this?

My code part is below:

```
input(Text) :-
   phrase(sentence(S), Text), 
   perform(S).
   %...
sentence(query(Q))     --> query(Q).

query(Query) --> 
   ['is', Thing, 'a', Category],
   { Query =.. [Category, Thing]}.

% here it will print true/false, is there a way in prolog to have it print yes/no, 
%like in other language: if(q){write("yes")}else{write("no")}
perform(query(Q))     :- Q.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Prolog there is a construct if/else:

```
perform(query(Q)) :-
  (  Q
  -> write(yes:Q)
  ;  write(no)
  ), nl.
```

When I need a stricter control on output formatting, I use [format](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%283,%274.31.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/format.html%27%29%29).
Not very friendly, but offers most of the usual options...